# Cómo configuro nominatim 3.2 con php 7.3?

Tags: php7

Actualicé de php7.2 a php7.3 y nominatim dejó de funcionar, ya instalé el paquete php7.3-pgsql pero igual sigue sin funcionar, el mensaje que arroja es

[DB Error: extension not found] ** pgsql://@/nominatim

claramente dice que no se encuentra la extensión, sin embargo

dpkg -s php7.3-pgsql

da como resultado

Package: php7.3-pgsql
Status: install ok installed

En lo relacionado al servidor se tiene instalado

Debian 9
Postgres 10
php 7.3
nominatim 3.2

Me podrían ayudar a resolver que me faltaría por hacer o que más debo configurar ? Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Problema resuelto....

Una mala configuración de nginx.conf fue la causa del problema (mal direccionamiento de php), corregido esto funciona ok

Caso cerrado

Comment: Para que tu aporte sea de ayuda a otros, puedes indicar que configuración estaba mal y como es que lo corregiste, de otro modo esto es solo un comentario y no una respuesta